# Show TableView Section Headers and Rows ios swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have an array with objects and i want to show Group Name in headers , but in the array some groups have same name, now i want to show single header for same group and create rows.

```
[
       {
         "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
         "Groups": "A",
         "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
       },
       {
         "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
         "Groups": "B",
         "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        },
        {
         "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
         "Groups": "A",
         "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        },
        {
         "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
         "Groups": "B",
         "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
       }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to use predicate. Using predicate you can make group(array) of dictionary which contains same Groups

Try bellow code.

```
let array = [
    [
        "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
        "Groups": "A",
        "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        ],
    [
        "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
        "Groups": "B",
        "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        ],
    [
        "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
        "Groups": "A",
        "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        ],
    [
        "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f",
        "Groups": "B",
        "primary_color": "#03a9f4"
        ]]

    var arrGroups = [String]()
    for dict in array {

        if !arrGroups.contains(dict["Groups"]!) {

            arrGroups.append(dict["Groups"]!)
        }
    }
    var arrTmp = [Array<Dictionary<String, String>>]()
    for i in 0..<arrGroups.count {

        var tmp:Array = array
        tmp = tmp.filter { ($0["Groups"]!).range(of: arrGroups[i], options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
        arrTmp.append(tmp)
    }
    print(arrTmp)
```

Each array in arrTmp will have dictionary that contains same Groups

So your `numberOfSections = arrTmp.count`

And `numberOfRowsInSection = arrTmp[section].count`

arrTmp will have

```
[[["primary_color": "#03a9f4", "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f", "Groups": "A"], ["primary_color": "#03a9f4", "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f", "Groups": "A"]], [["primary_color": "#03a9f4", "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f", "Groups": "B"], ["primary_color": "#03a9f4", "primary_dark_color": "#0d6d9f", "Groups": "B"]]]
```

Comment: Thannks @Priya can you please show me the arrays Values